# Adding slidemenu and sherloc actionbar in my projecct

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, mfslidemenu

I am new in android and Adding `slidemenu` and `sherlock actionbar` in my project, but getting this error :

> [2013-11-20 19:36:46 - Sample]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
>
> [2013-11-20 19:36:46 - Sample] Path: F:\My Data\actionbarsherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>
> [2013-11-20 19:36:46 - Sample]     Length: 271754
>
> [2013-11-20 19:36:46 - Sample]     SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
>
> [2013-11-20 19:36:46 - Sample] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

What is this error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have two or more same jar file(android-support-v4.jar) in your and all the library project that you are using and all of them does not have the same signature.

Either you can share one android-support-v4.jar among all the project or you can just copy android-support-v4.jar file to libs of all them.

Comment: @DinIslamMilon great :) and by the way you should accept the answer by checking it http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer , it does encourage developers like you and me to contribute more and more :) .